# How to avoid a priori absurd duplicate template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, c++20

In the context below, is there a way to not specialize the `exec` method? Note that they are almost identical. The example is deliberately small.

In my case, there are many methods that would have to be duplicated to simply change the cast, which would be a real paradox when using templates. Maybe the way of doing things is not the right way at all?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class D {
    public:
        D(uint8_t * mem) : m_mem(mem) {}
        uint8_t *m_mem;
        operator uint32_t*() { return reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem); }
};

template <typename T>
class C {
    public:
        C(T mem) : m_mem(mem) {}
        T m_mem;
        void exec();
};

template<>
void C<uint8_t*>::exec() {
    
    cout << "exec = " << *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << endl;
}

template<>
void C<D>::exec() {
    
    cout << "exec = " << *static_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t mem[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    
    C<uint8_t*> c1(mem);
    C<D>        c2(mem);
    
    c1.exec();
    c2.exec();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Write a helper template, say `AsUint32Ptr`, hide the cast there, specialize as needed. Then in `exec` et al, call this helper.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do an static cast on C<uint8_t*>

Comment: This only has defined behaviour if `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char` (or `char`). Why use `uint8_t` and not `unsigned char` here?

Comment: @perencia Because it won't compile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I suppose, but why?

Comment: Because `static_cast` cannot cast between two arbitrary unrelated pointer types. Roughly, `static_cast` can do implicit conversion (e.g. from a pointer to derived class to a pointer to base class, or any pointer to `void*`) and the inverse of an implicit conversion (from base to derived, from `void*` to any pointer type).

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 (and later), you can use the [`convertible_to` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) in a ["constexpr if"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statement, to choose which type of cast to use in a *single*  function template. The code below replaces your two specializations of `exec`

```cpp
#include <concepts>
template<class T>
void C<T>::exec()
{
    if constexpr (std::convertible_to<T, uint32_t*>) {
        std::cout << "exec = " << *static_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "exec = " << *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Before C++20 (or if you want to avoid concepts), there is the [`std::is_convertible` type-trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) that will achieve much the same thing:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
template<class T>
void C<T>::exec()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible<T, uint32_t*>::value) {
        std::cout << "exec = " << *static_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "exec = " << *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(m_mem) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really a nice way to do it. In case anyone is wondering about the impact of if/else : no trace of them in the generated binary.

Comment: @bitmapkid That's because of the `constexpr` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Most problems in computer science can be solved by adding a level of indirection. Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
uint32_t* AsUint32Ptr(uint8_t* mem) {
  return reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(mem);
}

uint32_t* AsUint32Ptr(D& mem) {
  return static_cast<uint32_t*>(mem);
}
```

With that, you don't need to specialize `exec` anymore:

```
template <typename T>
void C<T>::exec() {
    cout << "exec = " << *AsUInt32Ptr(m_mem) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Great solution and thanks for the concept of indirection.